# Finding angular displacement from displacement vectors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

I apologise in advance if the question is not clear. Suppose I have 4 points on the X-Y plane. Their relative positions with respect to each other are fixed. So any 2 points will have a fixed distance away from each other. In a short time interval, the X-Y plane undergoes a small rotation about a certain unknown point resulting in the displacement of the 4 points as shown in the image attached. If the displacement vectors of the 4 points are given, is it possible to calculate the angle of rotation of the X-Y plane? The axis of rotation is unknown.[An illustration of what I mean can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Cvj.png) Ideally I wish to find a mathematical expression with the displacement vectors with which i can compute the angular displacement.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The center of rotation is the common point of the perpendicular bisectors of the segments from a starting position of a point to the displaced position.

Use this point as center of a reference frame with an axis that passe thorough one of the points and find the angle of rotation.

Comment: Could you explain it mathematically? what i am looking for is a mathematical expression which would help me solve for the angle

Comment: @Appatakardot I’ll just add that If you’re working with real-world noisy data and imprecise computations instead of mathematical ideals, then it’s quite likely that these bisectors won’t all meet in a single point, so you’ll have to estimate this intersection in some way.

Comment: YES. I am working with real-world data which is why i am not satisfied with any of the responses i have received so far. If you have a suggestion on how i can approximate the angular displacement as accurately as possible. please indicate here